# with set :deploy_via, :remote_cache not working set :keep_releases, 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano

after first deploy with `set :deploy_via, :copy` for make changes in app now I'm using:

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
```

each time that I update changes make a new release but not remove the old releases.

I can see in releases folder:

```
20120325165324  20120326132816  20120326150033  20120326150716  20120326151632  20120326161602  20120326171203
```

I want only have 3 o 5 releases maximum.

I have in my deploy.rb:

```
set :keep_releases, 5
```

but this is does not works for me.

How can I remove old releases after deploy with `set :deploy_via, :remote_cache`

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You also need to either manually run cap deploy:cleanup, or simpler, just call in from within your deploy script via a callback, e.g. add this to `deploy.rb`

```
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```

which says, "when the restart task of deployment is complete, then run the cleanup task".  The default for `:keep_releases` is 5, so you don't really need to add it ... but it doesn't hurt.